# Stop propagation on an element, but not it's children?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `$(document).click() event` to close a sidebar element, which I am stopping event propagation on to make it intractable, but within that sidebar is an anchor that I want to respond to the `.click()` event and close the sidebar element, but I'm not sure how to do this.

My HTML code

```
  <nav class="sidebar">
      <li class="close"><a><span class="fa fa-close">&nbsp;</span>Close</a></li>
      <a><li class="menu">Explore</li></a>
      <a><li class="menu">Recent</li></a>
      <a><li class="menu">About</li></a>
      <a><li class="menu">Contact</li></a>
      <a class="signup"><li class="menu">Signup</li></a>
  </nav>
```

jQuery I am calling (var sidebar = $('.sidebar')):

```
var clickout = function() {
  $(document).click(function() {
      sidebar.removeClass('active');
      sidebar.animate({
        left: '-300px'
      }, 200, 'easeInOutCubic');
  });

    sidebar.click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First try to slove it without javascript. Use css3 ... provides such animation effects. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Second give your navbar an id="sidebar"
In jQuery change to:

```
var sidebar = $('#sidebar')
```

Further write:

```
sidebar.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation;
});
```

In case you don't want an instant call on this function.

Answer (score 0):

first of all.  Put the anchor inside the `li` tag

```
<nav class="sidebar">
  <li class="close"><a><span class="fa fa-close">&nbsp;</span>Close</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a>Explore</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a>Recent</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a>About</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a>Contact</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a class="signup">Signup</a></li>
</nav>
```

then below the `sidebar.click`..  add the ff

```
$('a',sidebar).click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

means it will search all anchors inside your sidebar and stops the parents event.